# How to log all published messages to a virtual host from a seperate application

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have two applications communicating with each other through a RabbitMQ virtual host, using Masstransit as an abstraction layer.

I am trying to create a third application which logs all the published messages to this virtual host, while, not knowing up front what these message types are.

If I knew the messages up front, it would be easy; I would just create some consumers. Unfortunate this is not the case.

I tried the [Observers](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/observers.html), but they only seem to work if the observed bus is the same as the one which sends the messages. So this wouldn't work cross-application.

From the [rabbit's docs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2010/10/19/exchange-to-exchange-bindings/) I found this would be easy by using rabbit MQ bindings, but, this does not seem to be supported: [Publish message using exchange and routing key using MassTransit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147212/publish-message-using-exchange-and-routing-key-using-masstransit)

I also tried: [How to log all Rabbit MQ messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937345/how-to-log-all-rabbit-mq-messages), but it seems a dead-end as well because I want to log the data in the custom format to a database.

It seems I am missing a trivial thing, but after searching whole day, I haven't found the desired result. Can you get me on the right track?

For bus configuration, in all 3 applications I am using the straight forward configuration pattern:

```
 _bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the queue names for the consuming services, you could create a new service with a new queue that would explicitly specify a binding to the exchange name of the other service queues. This would deliver a copy of every message delivered to that service to the new service.

The service could then consume the `JToken`, which would deliver the JSON body of the message to the consumer. By doing this, every message could then be translated/stored however you like.

```
class LogConsumer : IConsumer<JToken> {...}
```

Then, create the bindings in your receive endpoint:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "log-queue", ep =>
{
    ep.Bind("service1-queue");
    ep.Bind("service2-queue");
    ep.Consumer<LogConsumer>();
}
```

This should be enough to get you started!

Comment: Ah, wow, I'll give it a try. I also don't know the queues in advance but maybe I find a way to query them. Btw, I was looking into the `Bind` function before, but couldn't find it in this overload: `cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("logger", e => ...`);`. but I now see that the signature and type of `ep` is different in this overload.