# How can I track incoming messages in the rabbitmq queue via the console?

Tags: rabbitmq

Our rabbitmq is running under kubernetes, I can only go into the console of the pod itself, I cannot access the web interface of rabbitmq. I want to track if the right message is coming to queue from the application, how can I do this ?

I only found `rabbitmqctl list-queues`, which shows message statistics at the time

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to log all Rabbit MQ messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937345/how-to-log-all-rabbit-mq-messages)

Comment: I turned on tracing, but still can't track messages from kubernetes console. As i understood Firehose make dedicated queue for tracing, but problem is that i still cant see it from console.